# Half the power in my house goes out randomly and comes back on

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

Like the title says, half the power in my house will randomly go out.

And it's random rooms. No power in 1 upstairs room, but power in the other two. No power in main room of basement, but power in laundry room and bathroom of basement.

No power to 240v in kitchen, but power to lights and outlets in kitchen.

No power to living room or outdoor lights.

No breakers are tripped. No GFIs tripped.

The power will go out for a random period of time, and then come back on for a random period of time.

Has been happening for 2 days.

Any ideas what on earth is going on?

No outages or problems reported in my area. Asked a neighbor and they have no issues.

Comment: Probably a lose hot feed. Where the house loses power always the same?

Comment: Is there any pattern to which 120V circuits in your breaker panel lose power?

Comment: Try re-seating the circuit breakers in your panel.  And look for loose connections there (carefully).

Comment: Yes, always the same part of the house that loses power.  Turned off main power and checked for loose wires in panel, none that I can see.

Comment: I can contacted the electrical company in case I am intermittently losing one hot leg coming into the house. Although I am hoping that it is not somewhere between my house and the pole, as I think I am reaponsible for that.

Comment: Does the power availability change with running a 240v load (like a dryer, furnace or electric oven)? If so, that sounds like a lost neutral which is probably a PoCo issue at the pole or weatherhead. Calling the PoCo is your best bet.

Comment: your responsibility stops at the weatherhead.  You do not own the crimps on the weatherhead.  You also don't own the meter itself but you do own the meter pan.

Comment: You might need an electrician.... or an exorcist!

Answer (score 7):

### Lost hot wire from the utility

Call the utility emergency number and report an outage.  They'll have a truck out in an hour on a Sunday.

> And it's random rooms. No power in 1 upstairs room, but power in the other two. No power in main room of basement, but power in laundry room and bathroom of basement.

Not random at all!  I bet if you identified the breakers of the circuits that are out, they would be on every other row of the panel, [like described here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/110152/47125).

> The power will go out for a random period of time, and then come back on for a random period of time.

Not random either.  That is your tanked electric water heater, or other 240V load, cycling on and off.

A water heater and any large heat load is just a giant resistor between the two hot phases.

If one phase is dead, then it connects the dead  phase to the live phase *through the resistor*, causing it to re-energize.  Like borrowing electricity from your neighbor through way too many extension cords lol.    So modest 120V loads on that phase will now power up normally.  Greater loads on that phase will make the voltage sag considerably.

But here's the weird part, the current moving through that resistor is heating the resistor.  Modern water heaters are so well-insulated that they have very little loss.  Even this limited current is enough for them to "get ahead" and eventually reach their target temperature.  And then, they turn off!  Cutting power to those appliances.  So this (or another similar heater) would explain the random power-ups.

Turn off the breakers on all your 240V appliances (which you should do anyway, as this isn't good for them).  If the sporadic appliances are now dead as a doornail, that was it.

Answer (score 2):

Although you haven't said where in the world you live, it sounds like you have an intermittent connection to half of your incoming electrical service.  This is very serious, and suggest you contact your electrical provider ASAP and have them check out the lines going to your house and meter.  If they don't find anything amiss, call an electrician and have them check for a loose feeder connection in your breaker box.